# Input button separate the display button name and the value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set different button name display and want to pass different value.

i have tried the following code, but its display "yes" and also passing the value yes.

```
<input type="button" name="poll" value="Yes" width="100" onclick="getVote(this.value)"/>
```

basically i want to pass the value 1 and set the display name yes.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Using what? Javascript or php?

Comment: its an ajax...main php..

Comment: AJAX is an Asychronous XHR request. PHP is a serverside preprocessor. Javascript is what you will need to use to solve this problem. Please add the getVote function code to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this sounds too easy, so maybe i missunderstood something: just pass `1` instead of `this.value` to `getVote()`.

```
<input type="button" name="poll" value="Yes" width="100" onclick="getVote(1)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<button>` instead of `<input>`

```
<button name="name" value="value" type="submit">Your visible title</button>
```

Comment: This is the approach the op should use. I imagine they are trying to pass an Id, which they can set the value of this input to. Then they can pass `this.value` to their onclick function.